# Linear Back-ground effect over image not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a issue about animation of a background image when hovering. I want to make animation, when i hover image, transparent black linear image appear over it.

It was working before I add image, but when I add `src` attribute in `<img class="col-box-img">`, the linear back-ground image in `<div class="col-box-item-cover">` disappear when hovering.

But still the button's hovering effect in`<div class="col-box-item-container hover-effect>` is working. I can't understand why this issue isn't fixed.
Please help me..

```css
.col-box-img-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.col-box-img-box {
  position: relative;
}

.col-box-img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 100%; */
  left: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-style: none;
}

.column-box-item {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.col-box-item-container {
  height: 100%;
}

.hover-effect {
  transition: opacity .1s ease-in-out, visibility .1s ease-in-out;
  transition-property: opacity, visibility;
  transition-duration: 0.1s, 0.1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out, ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s;
}

.col-box:not(:hover) .hover-effect {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.col-box-item-cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .34) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, .338) 3.5%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .324) 7%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .306) 10.35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .285) 13.85%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .262) 17.35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .237) 20.85%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .213) 24.35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .188) 27.85%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .165) 31.35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .144) 34.85%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .126) 38.35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .112) 41.85%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .103) 45.35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 48.85%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .103) 52.35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .112) 55.85%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .126) 59.35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .144) 62.85%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .165) 66.35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .188) 69.85%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .213) 73.35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .237) 76.85%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .262) 80.35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .285) 83.85%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .306) 87.35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .324) 90.85%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .338) 94.35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .347) 97.85%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .35));
}

.col-box-item-box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, -webkit-min-content) auto;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, min-content) auto;
  grid-template-areas: "left right";
  gap: 20px;
  transition: opacity .1s ease-in-out, visibility .1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-box">
  <div class="col-box-container">
    <div class="col-box-cover-mold">
      <div class="col-box-background" style="background-color: rgb(217, 192, 163);"></div>
      <canvas width="32" height="32" class="col-box-background"></canvas>
      <div class="col-box-img-box">
        <!--image part -->
        <img class="col-box-img" alt="" sizes="(min-width: 1335px) 416px, (min-width: 992px) calc(calc(100vw - 72px) / 3), (min-width: 768px) calc(calc(100vw - 48px) / 2), 100vw" src="img.jpg" itemprop="" data-perf=""
          data-test="">
        <div style="padding-bottom: %" ;></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="column-box-item">
    <div class="col-box-item-container hover-effect">
      <!--Linear background -->
      <div class="col-box-item-cover"></div>
      <!--button -->
      <div class="col-box-item-mold">
        <div class="col-box-item-box">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did not understand exactly. Now it is hovering, but there is no image.

Comment: In my actual code i add `src="image ur"` in `<img class="col-box-img">`, It works before i add `src` but when i add `arc` in `<img>`, the hovering effect on `<div class="col-box-item-cover">` which is linear-background disappear.

Comment: I checked the code, there was no problem with the hover, a transparent layer falls on the image. what is the problem? I used Chrome.

Comment: I've fixed the problem by redesigning whole code. The code of linear-background works well alone. But in whole code, the hovering effect is gone. I think it's because of the parent's grid system.. When I change parents' element to 'flex'. The hovering effect of linear-gradient background  works well :-)! Thank you for reply